# LoRa MBED and Arduino libraries not compatible

Tags: arduino, stm32, mbed, lora

Can anyone work out why I can't get these two libraries to communicate to each other over LoRa?
https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa
https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-semtech-lora-rf-drivers/tree/master/SX1276

I can get each library to communicate with another device using the same lib and even compile the arduino code onto the stm32 and have an stm32 and arduino board talk fine but using one of each library they won't. As far as I can tell it can only be a LoRa settings difference.

Arduino Settings

```
#define TX_POWER 17 // valid range 2-17 on BOOST_PIN, 2-20 on PA_OUTPUT_RFO_PIN
#define TX_PA_PIN PA_OUTPUT_PA_BOOST_PIN
#define SPREADING_FACTOR 7     // 6 -> 12
#define SIGNAL_BANDWIDTH 250E3 // 125E3 //250E3 //62.5E3
#define LORA_FREQUENCY 915E6
#define SYNC_WORD 0x12

...

while (!LoRa.begin(LORA_FREQUENCY)) {
  Serial.println(".");
  delay(10);
}

// Configure the LoRa Radio
LoRa.setSpreadingFactor(SPREADING_FACTOR);
LoRa.setSignalBandwidth(SIGNAL_BANDWIDTH);
LoRa.setTxPower(TX_POWER, TX_PA_PIN);
LoRa.setSyncWord(SYNC_WORD);
LoRa.setCodingRate4(5);
LoRa.setPreambleLength(8);
LoRa.disableCrc();
LoRa.disableInvertIQ();
```

MBED Settings

```
#define frequency 915E6
#define bandwidth 1 //LoRa: [0: 125 kHz, 1: 250 kHz, 2: 500 kHz, 3: Reserved]
#define datarate 7 // SPREADING FACTOR //LoRa: [6: 64, 7: 128, 8: 256, 9: 512, 10: 1024, 11: 2048, 12: 4096  chips]
#define coderate 1 //LoRa: [1: 4/5, 2: 4/6, 3: 4/7, 4: 4/8]
#define bandwidth_afc 0
#define preamble_len 8
#define symb_timeout 0
#define fix_len false
#define crc_on false
#define freq_hop_on false
#define hop_period 0
#define iq_inverted false
#define rx_continuous true
#define power 17
#define fdev 0
#define timeout 100000

...

lora.set_tx_config (modem_type::MODEM_LORA, 
                    power, 
                    fdev,
                    bandwidth, 
                    datarate,
                    coderate, 
                    preamble_len,
                    fix_len, 
                    crc_on, 
                    freq_hop_on,
                    hop_period, 
                    iq_inverted, 
                    timeout
);

lora.set_rx_config (modem_type::MODEM_LORA,
                    bandwidth,
                    datarate, 
                    coderate,
                    bandwidth_afc, 
                    preamble_len,
                    symb_timeout, 
                    fix_len,
                    payload_len,
                    crc_on, 
                    freq_hop_on, 
                    hop_period,
                    iq_inverted, 
                    rx_continuous
);

lora.init_radio(&lora_events);
lora.set_channel(frequency);
lora.set_public_network(false);

lora.receive();
```

Have tried setting both sync words to either `0x12` or `0x34` too.

Comment: Have you also independently tested mbed library on both STM32 and Arduino? As you tested Arduino library with both and they communicated just fine, do the same using mbed library. This will verify if the mbed library is also functional. Once you have the verdict that both libraries are functional, you can have a closer look inside libraries to see how they are treating config.

Comment: The mbed library communicates fine on both stms

Comment: Well there's a starting point to dig further. I would start with changing the `freq_hop_on`, `hop_period`, `rx_continuous`, `fdev` parameters one by one at MBED end. Make sure to test independently with MBED device to MBED device first when making these changes

Comment: Consider making both log all of their radio register writes, and then compare the logs when each is attempting the same task (ie, compare transmit to transmit or receive to receive) . Some things will probably be in different order but your should be able to treat one as a checklist and find the corresponding operations in the other until you discover an actual difference.